# How can I get the count of orders placed from my database?

Tags: php, sql

I am preparing a chart which will display the number of orders placed for a particular day in the current month and year. I wanted the count of orders placed for each day.
I am showing the count of orders on the y-axis and the day on the x-axis.
In my database, there is table called "order" in which order data is placed: order date, user_id, order_price, etc. For example, if on 4 July, 10 orders are placed, on 5 july, 20 orders are placed, and so on.

How can I get the count of orders placed for day of the current month?

Comment: MySql ? Oracle ? what are the names of the columns ? what query did you try to run ?

Comment: Try breaking this up into smaller issues and researching each one then if you stuck on any part come back here. We can't do it for you!

Comment: i am using mysql with php and name  of the columns are user_id,discount,service_tax,coupon_discount,total,date_Of_order. and need sum suggestion how to get the count of orders placed for individual day

Answer (score 3):

i didn't get what you mean correctly but here are two solutions for what i could collect from all the comments

- You need to count the number of orders placed in a particular day

if you want just the order on a particular date you can use this query

```
 select count(*)as "Order Placed" from examp where date_of_order = '2012-01-15';
```

- you need a list of order placed (date wise)

> select DATE_FORMAT(date_of_order,'%M %Y') as "Date",count(*) as "Order
>   Placed" from examp group by date_of_order;

see it working here

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/69782/7)

EDIT:

Now if you want a list for a single month simply use a where clause.

```
select DATE_FORMAT(date_of_order,'%M %Y') as "DATE",count(*) as "Order Placed" 
from examp
 where month(date_of_order) = '2'  group by date_of_order;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just adding onto what Ankit has said..

When grouping by day you might have a problem if your date_of_order includes a timestamp:

e.g. 2012-01-01 12:37:01

If it does use DATEADD to round the time down to midnight so that you can group by day.

```
    DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, [date_of_order]),0)
```

It will then look like:

2012-01-01 00:00:00

So your code should be like:

```
    SELECT 
    date_of_order,
    COUNT(date_of_order)  
    FROM examp 
    GROUP BY DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, [date_of_order]),0)
```

Comment: A very nice point... but DATEADD is not supported by Mysql (i guess) but yes it works with SQLServer.

Comment: as DATEADD is sqlserver function and supported in mysql than what is alternative for mysql